# Nuxt js: how to use proxy in laravel sanctum?

Tags: proxy, nuxtjs, laravel-sanctum

Nuxt js NOTE: It is highly recommended to use proxy to avoid CORS and same-site policy issues.

I couldn't understand the use of "target" and "pathRewrite
" in the proxy.

who can describe them?

if my backend(laravel) URL be localhost:8000 and my frontend(Nuxt) URL be localhost:3000 then how should I config it?

[image: image from auth.nuxtjs.org]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `Axios` proxy in **NuxtJS** like this:

```
export default {
  axios: {
    credentials: true,
    proxy: true,
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/': process.env.API_URL,
  },
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/auth/login',
      logout: '/auth/login',
      callback: '/auth/login',
      home: '/feed',
    },
    strategies: {
      laravelSanctum: {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: 'api', // note the URL here.
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/auth/login',
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/auth/logout',
          },
          user: {
            url: '/auth/me',
          },
        },
      },
    }
  }
}
```

> I couldn't understand the use of "target" and "pathRewrite " in the proxy.

Let's say your `API_URL` is `localhost:8000`.

If you write proxy config like this:

```
proxy: {
  '/api': process.env.API_URL,
},
```

It will add `/api` at the end of the URL. So your `API_URL` will be `localhost:8000/api`.
Now you may call API request with Axios like this:

```
this.$axios.$get('api/me');
```

In the behind, it will call to this URL: `localhost:8000/api/me`.

If you write your proxy config like this:

```
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: process.env.API_URL,
    pathRewrite: { '^/api': '/' }
  }
},
```

It will remove `/api` from the end of the URL. So your `API_URL` will be `localhost:8000`.

Now you may call API request with Axios like this:

```
this.$axios.$get('api/me');
```

In the behind, it will call to this URL: `localhost:8000/me`.

Enjoy :)

Comment: after using your guide I got this error:   ERROR  [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/getArticles to http://loaclhost:8000/ [ENOTFOUND] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_s
ystem_errors)

Comment: @Hamzeh Did you add `@nuxtjs/proxy` in your dependency? Copied from axios.nuxtjs.org
> Note: It is not required to manually register @nuxtjs/proxy module, but it does need to be in your dependencies.

Comment: yeah, I used it. if I want to show you my code, Do I have to answer my question or edit my question here?

Comment: @Hamzeh You may need to edit your question.

Comment: thank you. I think I could solve my issue with your guide. I used proxy:  {'/api': process.env.API_URL,} it work on localhost, now I need to deploy it and test it on the host.

Comment: If it works, you may mark it as complete :)